# Reverse the [php5.2] → [php52] synonym

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I have no idea why it's in the state it is in now, but surely the logical tag for PHP 5.2 specific problems should be [php5.2](/questions/tagged/php5.2) and not [php52](/questions/tagged/php52)?

Indeed, there are no [php53](/questions/tagged/php53) questions out there but instead [php5.3](/questions/tagged/php5.3). No synonym exist for that too.

---

**Edit:** Of course we could also go with [what sth suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79936/reverse-the-php5-2-php52-synonym/79944#79944) and go with [php-5.2](/questions/tagged/php-5.2) and [php-5.3](/questions/tagged/php-5.3), but that would require two synonyms/tag merges.

Comment: Honestly I'd rather work with PHP version 52 than 5.2.  The frobulating matrix representation of twelfth dimension math makes adding a `<blink>` tag to my site *so* much easier, not to mention the obvious increase in performance due to the newly implemented ooblong engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [php52](/questions/tagged/php52) is now [php-5.2](/questions/tagged/php-5.2) (old synonym removed)
- [php5.3](/questions/tagged/php5.3) is now [php-5.3](/questions/tagged/php-5.3)

This makes them consistent in relation to each other and with other `tag-version.minor` tags in the system.

Answer (score 8):

[php-5.2](/questions/tagged/php-5.2) would be even better.